# If statement in series.html within Jekyll blog

Tags: jekyll

I have some language in a series.html file located in the _includes section of my jekyll blog, pasted below:

```
{% if page.series %}
{% assign count = '0' %}
{% assign idx = '0' %}
{% for post in site.posts reversed %}
    {% if post.series == page.series %}
        {% capture count %}{{ count | plus: '1' }}{% endcapture %}
        {% if post.url == page.url %}
            {% capture idx %}{{count}}{% endcapture %}
        {% endif %}
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
{% endif %}
```

While it does connect the posts that are designated as part of a series within the post's YAML layout, it also connects other posts as part of a series as well even though they are not designated as 'series' in the YAML front matter of the post, despite the if statement.  This results in all of my posts being part of a general "series" which I do not want.  I just want to designate some posts to be part of a series while others are just unique one-off posts.

I have tried the following:

1. Not specifying a series at all within the YAML front matter
2. setting series: False
3. setting series: None

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT :**

What's actually happening in your ***[post.html](https://github.com/thedatasleuth/thedatasleuth.github.io/blob/master/_layouts/post.html)*** template is that not all your html is conditionally printed.

Everything in ***_includes/series.html*** is conditioned by `page.series != null`, but the content of your `<div class="panel seriesNote">` is always printed.

You need to move this code (all `<div class="panel seriesNote">[...]</div>`) in your condition in ***_includes/series.html***.

```
{% if page.series != null %}
[...]
{% endfor %}
<div class="panel seriesNote">  <<<< moved code
[...]
</div>                          <<<< end moved code
{% endif %}
```

**END EDIT**

If you don't set `series` in your front matter, `page.series` is `nil`.

If you leave it empty, it's also `nil`.

So, `{% if page.series != null %}` will help you select only pages where series is set to a value.

**Note about counters :**

`{% assign count = '0' %}` => count is a string

`{% capture count %}{{ count | plus: 1 }}{% endcapture %}` => count is a string

If you do :

{% assign count = 0 %} => count is an integer

{% assign count = count | plus: 1 %} => count is an integer

Be aware of this when you use you counter in a comparison, it can leads to errors by trying to compare strings and integers.

Comment: I have changed `{% if page.series %}` to `{% if page.series != null %}` in the series.html file in the _includes folder as suggested, and still, posts without series set in the YAML are somehow being connected to other posts without YAML series.  Other thoughts?

Comment: Did you have a repository url ? This can help.

Comment: depending on your interest level, i have two other questions posted in my profile related to my jekyll blog.  for someone who's well-versed in jekyll and liquid, i suspect they are pretty easy to answer.

Comment: I included your suggested code like this: `<div class="panel seriesNote">
  {% if page.series != null %}
  {% assign count = '0' %}
  {% assign idx = '0' %}
  {% for post in site.posts reversed %}
      {% if post.series == page.series %}
          {% capture count %}{{ count | plus: '1' }}{% endcapture %}
          {% if post.url == page.url %}
              {% capture idx %}{{count}}{% endcapture %}
          {% endif %}
      {% endif %}
  {% endfor %}
  {% endif %}` and still it is linking "un-seriesed" posts.  It also had the added effect of deleting my related posts on side.

Comment: Well done - that did it.  Thank you for your patience and guidance.  Looks awesome.